# What counts as a symmetry of the system and what a symmetry of the order paramter?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry

According to (Yeomans, 1992; pg27) when we have short-range interactions critical exponents depend only on the dimensionality of the system and the symmetries of the order parameter.

I am confused about what counts as a symmetry of the order parameter here. Clearly e.g. $m\leftrightarrow -m$ in the Ising model is a symmetry of the Order parameter. But take for example spatial inversion symmetry:
$$\phi\left( \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}\right)\leftrightarrow \phi\left( \begin{pmatrix} -x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}\right)$$
does this still count as a symmetry of the order parameter or is it a symmetry of the system?

p.s. by system here I mean anything which is not the order-parameter.

Comment: Surely, if the *configuration* of the system is invariant under a symmetry operation, then it is a symmetry of *both* the system and order parameter. Otherwise it a symmetry of the order parameter alone.

Comment: @lemon Fair point. I guess then my question is weather the use of the term symmetries of the order parameter by Yeomans includes symmetries that are symmetries of both the system and the order parameter.